# About unity 3d load assetbundle difference

Tags: unity-game-engine

Under normal circumstances, I load assetbundle like this

```
WWW www = WWW.LoadFromCacheOrDownload("http://x.x.x.x/player.unity3d", 3);
yield return www;
```

but I want to load assetbundle by difference file, for example
I have a difference file like: `http://x.x.x.x/player.unity3d.diff`

I generate the diff by bsdiff ([daemonology.net/bsdiff](http://www.daemonology.net/bsdiff/))

My question is; how can I load assetbundle by player.unity3d.diff?

I am trying to google it, but I not found anything.

Comment: How did you generate the diff? Are you saying you want to really update something you've already previously loaded?

Comment: i generate the diff by bsdiff(http://www.daemonology.net/bsdiff/)

Comment: That simply isn't supported by Unity. I'm afraid you're out of luck there other than manually applying a diff on downloaded asset bundles and then loading the result. (If that works at all).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unity doesn't support loading bsdiff'ed files, but you could implement it yourself. Example:

```
// Load asset bundle
WWW www1 = WWW.LoadFromCacheOrDownload("original.bundle");
// Load diff
WWW www2 = WWW.LoadFromCacheOrDownload("updated.bundle.diff");

// Get bytes for both assets
byte[] original = www1.bytes;
byte[] diff = www2.bytes;

// Apply diff
byte[] updated = ApplyBspatch(original, diff);

// You can save updated bundle at this point to a file.

// Finally, create asset bundle
AssetBundle bundle = AssetBundle.CreateFromMemory(updated);
```

Here's one of bsdiff implementations in C# you could use to do the patching: https://github.com/LogosBible/bsdiff.net